# How do I dynamically match components in Gatsby to ACF on WordPress pages?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, dynamic, gatsby, advanced-custom-fields

So I am dynamically creating pages in Gatsby from WordPress using the *gatsby-source-wordpress* plugin and necessary WP plugins. However, if I want to add ACF to specific pages on WordPress, how do I go about matching the ACF fields from the GraphQL query to components - presumably taking the query as component props?

Comment: I have done this in the past, you have to install ACF to Rest API plugin, checkout this [post](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9615#issuecomment-535737514)

Comment: but what if the page is being created dynamically using createPage function in gatsby-config? Wondering how I could go about matching the acf to components - or is this not possible unless creating pages manually in the gatsby src/pages?

Comment: check out [this starter template](https://github.com/GatsbyCentral/gatsby-starter-wordpress). Here is how you can [query posts](https://github.com/GatsbyCentral/gatsby-starter-wordpress/blob/master/src/templates/post.js#L94)

Comment: nice, while go through and dissect this - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your login inside gatsby-node, for gatsby how to create pages. Based on template, id, acf, or whatever you want.

Short example i did for page templates:

```
    ...
    let pageTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/page.js`);
        
    _.each(pages, ({ node: page }) => {
         switch (page.template) {
             case 'template_about.php':
                  pageTemplate = path.resolve(`./src/templates/about.js`);
             break;
    createPage({
         path: `/${page.slug}/`,
         component: pageTemplate,
         context: {
         id: page.id,
   },});
```